# RegEx pattern to match 101 - 999

Tags: javascript, regex

Can someone provide an example JavaScript regular expression to match 101 - 999? I'm having a hard time figuring it out.

Comment: Are you sure you need a RegEx for this? Won't `n >= 101 && n <= 999` do?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
^(10[1-9]|1[1-9][0-9]|[2-9][0-9]{2})$
```

Comment: Definitely better than mine ;) only catch is that this requires the match to be at the beginning and end, thus failing when matching inline text. You could use `\b(10[1-9]|1[1-9][0-9]|[2-9][0-9]{2})\b instead`, which lessens the restriction to word boundary.

Comment: @r3mus: Yes that is true word boundaries can also be used.